# imagepng shows "cannot be displayed" error

Tags: php, gd

I dunno why, but there's something weird about imagepng. Whenever i use `imagepng($image_p,NULL,9);` it uploads the file and displays it on the page but when i use `imagepng($image_p,'upload/test.png',9);` it does upload the image, but the page returns the message "The image *_* cannot be displayed, because it contains errors." and the succeeding codes will not work.

Can you guys please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

here's the more detailed code:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filename2);
$size = getimagesize($filename2);
$w = $size[0];
$h = $size[1];
$nw = 200;
$nh = 200;
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($nw,$nh);
imagecopyresampled($image_p,$im,0,0,$_GET['left']*1,$_GET['top']*1,$nw,$nh,$_GET['width']*1,$_GET['height']*1);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$fn1 = "fin_".substr(uniqid(md5(rand()), true),0,10).".".$extension;
imagepng($image_p,'upload/'.$fn1,9);
```

Comment: how are you displaying your file? Show full code, can't "guess", but best "guess", is the way you're echoing it.

Comment: It's because it's not being echoed once the process has finished. Try either `echo $fn1;` or `echo $im;` after your last line, or whatever is the image variable being saved.

Comment: tried echoing after imagepng(), but it still gives me the "cannot be displayed" error.

Comment: then it's your path, it's gotta be

Comment: i tried changing `'upload/'.$fn1` to `'test.png'` as well, and it also produced the same error.

the only way it worked fine was when i changed it to `NULL` instead

Comment: and what if you tried `imagepng($image_p,upload/$fn1,9);`

Comment: still produced the same error :(

Comment: I don't know what else it could be then.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `header('Content-Type: image/png');` and it worked. Unbelievable.

Thank you very much Fred ii for trying to help me out. I really appreciate your time.